# How to get SHA1 certificate fingerprint for Google Map API key

Tags: 14.04, java

I need SHA1 certificate fingerprint to get Google Map API key but when I enter

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

in terminal it shows that **keytool can be found in following packages**

```
The program 'keytool' can be found in the following packages:
 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

the file **keytool** already exists in `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/bin` even though terminal displays this kinda message.

What's wrong with it?

I use Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

Comment: What is the result of
    `which java`
and
    `readlink -f /usr/bin/java`?

Comment: Java 8 is not in the 14.04 repositories, only Java 6 and 7, as you can see from the message. How did you installed Java 8?

Comment: I have been using java 8 since 6 six months and I solved the problem by the way :) @HontváriLevente

Comment: Than it would be nice if you write down your solution, so if somebody finds this page, he get something valuable.

Comment: Or at the very least delete this question, especially if you installed java in a non-standard way and won't be posting an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/bin` isn't in `$PATH`.

Just use the full path to invoke it.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_25/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Comment: Also, the path can be /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/keytool if you installed it with sudo

Comment: I am still getting same error. :(
even if jdk is in opt and I used  /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/keytool

My command is :
/opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_71/bin/keytool -list -v -keystore /home/htech22/Desktop/F/Flow/FlowKeystoreFile.jks -alias flow